# Install JRE Ubuntu using Alien command

Tags: java, ubuntu, rpm, alien

```
sudo alien -i jre-8u231-linux-x64.rpm

warning: jre-8u231-linux-x64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: jre-8u231-linux-x64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
warning: jre-8u231-linux-x64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
Warning: Skipping conversion of scripts in package jre1.8: postinst postrm prerm
Warning: Use the --scripts parameter to include the scripts.
warning: jre-8u231-linux-x64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
dpkg --no-force-overwrite -i jre1.8_1.8.0231-1_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 143050 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack jre1.8_1.8.0231-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking jre1.8 (1.8.0231-1) over (1.8.0231-1) ...
Setting up jre1.8 (1.8.0231-1) .
```

i am trying install JRE in my Ubuntu box, during the installation i am getting below warning message, and also i am not sure whether jre is installed correctly or not .

```
 java -version

Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install default-jre            
apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless 

Ask your administrator to install one of them.
```

while running java version in terminal, i'm not getting anything from the terminal.

Can you please help me on this

Comment: Hi Joachim, can you please help me on this

Comment: Have you looked at [these instructions](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64rpm_install.xml)? They say you have to put yourself in the directory where you want to install it before installing. Also, you'll then need to add to your `$PATH` to point to the resulting `bin` directory.

Comment: Hi Federico, Already i'm executing my rpm package from /usr/lib/java only.

Comment: Ok, then you need to add the `bin` directory to your `$PATH`. In the meantime you can test that it's working by running java with the full path (should be `/usr/lib/java/bin/java`)